# Conjunctive Regular Path Queries and Subgraph Isomorphism

Tags: graphs, database-theory

How do conjunctive regular path queries and subgraph isomorphism relate to each other? It seems that conjunctive regular path queries are a specialised form of subgraph isomorphism.

The follow is the definition of a conjunctive regular path query given in ["Expressive Languages for Path Queries over
Graph-Structured Data"](http://users.dcc.uchile.cl/~pbarcelo/pods10.pdf):

> A conjunctive regular path query (CRPQ) $Q$ over a finite alphabet
>   $\Sigma$ is an expression of the form:
>
> $Ans(\bar{z}) \leftarrow \bigwedge_{1\leq i \leq m} (x_i , \pi_i, y_i), \bigwedge_{1\leq j \leq t} L_j(\omega_j)$
>
> where,
>
> (i) $m > 0, t ≥ 0$,
>
> (ii) each $L_j$ is a regular expression over $\Sigma$,
>
> (iii) $\bar{x} = (x_1, \cdots , x_m), \bar{y} = (y_1, . . . , y_m)$
>   and $\bar{z}$ are tuples of node variables,
>
> (iv) $\{\pi_1, \cdots , \pi_m \}$ are distinct path variables,
>
> (v) $\{\omega_1, \cdots, \omega_t\}$ are distinct path variables and
>   each $\omega_j$ is among the $\pi_i$’s, and
>
> (vi) $\bar{z}$ is a tuple of node variables among $\bar{x}$ and
>   $\bar{y}$.
>
> The atom $Ans(\bar{z})$ is the head of the query, the expression
>   on the right of the $\leftarrow$ is its body.